# Unable to run Jasper report : The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

I have the reports in `reports\templates\Contractor_Bill.jrxml` and the results in  `reports\results\`. It works fine in Netbeans 6.5, but when i copy the `dist` folder containing exec jar file to a new place and run the jar it throws this exception.

I also created the report folder in the new place, and it still generates the same exception.

```
Aug 5, 2009 10:11:58 PM cbs.ui.ReportUI GenerateReport
SEVERE: null
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report java source files : C:\Documents and Settings\Mohanish Timble\Desktop\sw\Contractor_Bill_old_1249490518017_973633.java
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler.compileClasses(JRJavacCompiler.java:93)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractClassCompiler.compileUnits(JRAbstractClassCompiler.java:67)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:190)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:220)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:153)
        at cbs.ui.ReportUI.GenerateReport(ReportUI.java:202)
        at cbs.ui.ReportUI.btnGenerateBillActionPerformed(ReportUI.java:151)
        at cbs.ui.ReportUI.access$100(ReportUI.java:38)
        at cbs.ui.ReportUI$2.actionPerformed(ReportUI.java:85)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler.compileClasses(JRJavacCompiler.java:62)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 37 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java: 138)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:57)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:402)
        at cbs.ui.ReportUI.GenerateReport(ReportUI.java:218)
        at cbs.ui.ReportUI.btnGenerateBillActionPerformed(ReportUI.java:151)
        at cbs.ui.ReportUI.access$100(ReportUI.java:38)
        at cbs.ui.ReportUI$2.actionPerformed(ReportUI.java:85)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 5):

Include the Jar jasper-compiler-jdt in the lib folder

Answer (score 0):

> For versione of jasper-reports >= 6.0.0, the jar used to compile is called

```
ecj-x.x.x.jar
```

See [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports) to get correct version number of ecj for relative version of jasper reports.